# Pandas filter df based on groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame and would like to select only entries with the top 25% of scores in each group.

I've been trying to follow the logic of the "Group by: split-apply-combine" tutorial:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html but can't seem to understand the "combine" step.

My dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'read_id': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k'], 
        'group_id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 , 2],
        'score': [0.8, 0.82, 0.99, 0.85, 0.87, 0.83, 0.84, 0.97, 0.97, 0.8, 0.84],
    }
)
```

I would like to filter to names 'c', 'h', 'i'; which are in the top 25% of their group

```
groups = df.groupby("group_id")
high_scoring = groups.apply(lambda g: g.score.gt(g.score.quantile(0.75)))
```

This looks like it's filtering correctly and produces a Series object:

```
print(high_scoring)

group_id    
1         0     False
          1     False
          2      True
          3     False
          4     False
2         5     False
          6     False
          7      True
          8      True
          9     False
          10    False
```

However I can't the use that to filter the original DataFrame, as the "group_id" 'column' seems to be causing havoc

```
df_good_only = df[high_scoring]

...
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I filter the data based on the value distributions in a group?

I would like the output DataFrame to look like this:

```
read_id group_id    score
c   1   0.99
h   2   0.97
i   2   0.97
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change to `transform` , index level not match will return the issue during filter with condition

```
out = df[df.score>df.groupby("group_id").score.transform(pd.Series.quantile,0.75)]
Out[79]: 
  read_id  group_id  score
2       c         1   0.99
7       h         2   0.97
8       i         2   0.97
```

In your case fix the code

```
df[high_scoring.reset_index(level=0,drop=True)]
```

Comment: The `transform` approach works as I expect on my toy example, thanks! However, when I apply it on my 'read-data' I get: `IndexError: Column(s) score already selected`. Do you know what could cause that?